Do transfer of ownership needed in ad hoc app?
My company has an app that developed by a vendor, they used their apple developer account and not ours. So now when we want to take control of the app when we need to add more UDID to the app and that we don't have to pay them.
I have recompile the app per their instructions using our developer account, but now we can't install it on the new phones. It crashed and then disappeared.
Do they have to transfer the app to us or we can use our developer account and it will work?
Sorry if this confuses as I don't have a background in programming or making app. Thank you very much for your help.
